# Which theologies / denominations adopt the "already but not yet" paradigm for the Kingdom of God?

Tags: comparative-christianity, kingdom-of-god, inaugurated-eschatology

When reading this *GotQuestion* [article on "already but not yet"](https://www.gotquestions.org/already-not-yet.html) paradigm that I often hear in evangelical sermons, I was surprised that the article author emphasized its popularity with charismatics groups.  I thought this paradigm has been adopted a lot more widely, especially among non-charismatic evangelical groups as well.

Which led me to ask this question: **which non-charismatic theologies / denominations *also* adopt this paradigm**?  On the surface I thought this is a straightforward reading of NT verses about the arrival of the Kingdom of God that even Catholics and Eastern Orthodox would also adopt.

- The *GotQuestion* article as well as the *Wikipedia* article on a closely related concept [inaugurated eschatology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inaugurated_eschatology) says that the 2 aspects "already" and "not yet" to the Kingdom of God was first proposed by [Geerhardus Vos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geerhardus_Vos) who is *non*-charismatic **Reformed**.
- I also frequently hear an equivalent analogy in terms of "D-Day" (already) vs. "V-Day" (not yet), that the same *Wikipedia* article attributes to [Oscar Cullmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscar_Cullmann) who is **Lutheran**.
- Then there is also the famous quote of [God landing in this enemy-occupied world in disguise](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/437442-why-is-god-landing-in-this-enemy-occupied-world-in-disguise) from *Mere Christianity* that I often hear pastors use in association with the Kingdom of God, a book authored by C.S. Lewis who was definitely a non-charismatic **Anglican** but who wrote for all denominations.

The following quote from the *Wikipedia* article on the [Kingdom of God (Christianity)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_God_(Christianity)) indicates that not all theologies subscribe to inaugurated eschatology:

> The term "kingdom of God" has been used to mean Christian lifestyle, a method of world evangelization, the rediscovery of charismatic gifts and many other things. **Others relate it not to our present or future earthly situation but to the world to come.** The interpretation of the phrase is often based on the theological leanings of the scholar-interpreter. A number of theological interpretations of the term the Kingdom of God have thus appeared in its eschatological context, e.g., apocalyptic, realized or Inaugurated eschatologies, yet no consensus has emerged among scholars.

I would like the answer to **supply references to as many theologies / denominations as possible, that explicitly adopt** either the "already but not yet" or the "inaugurated eschatology" paradigm to their understanding of the Kingdom of God.

Comment: It is already here but is awaiting the Revelation of the Son of Man from the spirit realm. Then the new Jerusalem will come down from God on the new earth like a bride prepared for her husband. All for the glory and majesty of God.

Comment: It's probably almost universal, though maybe not with that exact terminology. Note that non-charismatic/Pentecostal Christians often accuse charistmatic/Pentecostal Christians of having an "over-realised eschatology".

Answer (score 2):

Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints

- doesn't necessarily use phrase 'already but not yet' but when referencing [kingdom of God](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/gs/kingdom-of-god-or-kingdom-of-heaven?lang=eng) there is the indication of while living/taking part of the kingdom of God on earth (now) there is more to come (2nd coming/millenium)

  > The kingdom of God on earth is The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints (D&C 65). The purpose of the Church is to prepare its members to live forever in the celestial kingdom or kingdom of heaven. However, the scriptures sometimes call the Church the kingdom of heaven, meaning that the Church is the kingdom of heaven on earth.

Comment: I like the idea of using a community wiki for this one.  LDS is the first one out of the gate :-).  BTW, do LDS consider non-LDS Christians to also belong to the Kingdom of God on earth or membership in LDS church is strictly necessary?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple membership in LDS would be necessary to be part of the kingdom of God (from my reading/understanding). This does not mean mean they aren't Christian

Comment: I expected that answer.  Maybe I should ask another `comparative-christianity` question on which denominations strictly identify membership in their churches with membership in the Kingdom of God.  I wonder what the Catholics and the Eastern Orthodox would say.

Answer (score 1):

**Geehardus Vos** Geehardus Vos (Dutch Reformed) is credited as first using the phrase now interpreted as *already but not yet.* Or more descriptive, *inaugurated eschatology*. (See **Teaching of Jesus Concerning the Kingdom of God and the Church** (1903).)

**George Eldon Ladd** Professor Ladd taught at Fuller Seminary, (an interdenominational seminary), and wrote on the Kingdom of God. He picked up the thought of the *inaugurated eschatology* (Already, but not yet). And was quite influential in spready this concept. (See **The Presence of the Future**(1973, previously, **Jesus and the Kingdom**; and **A New Heaven and Earth**)

John Wimber, founder of Vineyard Ministries (Charismatic), is said to have been greatly influenced by Ladd's writings.

**R.G. Clouse** In a book that presented the four main views of the Millennium, R.G. Clouse presented this similar view. (**The Meaning of the Kingdom: Four Views**, 1977) This book has circulated around many Evangelical church denominations.

The concept of "Already, but not yet" has been adopted by the present faculty of Portland Bible College (Charismatic, part of Mannahouse Church, Portland).

**ADDENDUM**

**Manuscript Research** I have written a manuscript that was researched with commentary on **every time** the word, **Kingdom** was used in the New Testament Greek. (And a few times, *king*.) And there is no doubt that Jesus came to inaugurate and establish the Kingdom of God on earth at His First Coming. (Daniel 2:44, Matthew 6:10, 9:35, 13:19,38, Luke 12:32, 22:29, Col. 1:13) A Kingdom that will endure until the End when it is finally "delivered p to the Father." (1 Corinthians 15:24)

However, some commentators and Bible teachers, have taken great pains to delay the full establishment of Jesus's Kingdom in their view. They admit a quasi reality of the Kingdom now ("already") but look forward to a greater earthly manifestation down the road of time("not yet"). (We're not here speaking of Dispensationalism with its Jewish overtones.)

But what is not taken into consideration when addressing the "seemingly future -leaning verses, is the fact of a period of **transition.** It took 40 years of **overlap**, wherein the Old Testament covenant was finalized, and the New Covenant was completely inaugurated. (From 30-70 A.D.)

At 30 A.D. the full manifestation was future, looking forward to 70 A.D. But by 70 A.D the Old Covenant was ended completely, looking back.  The verses about the *future* were not referring to an End of the World era, but to the complete establishment beginning in 70 A.D (Colossians 1:13)

Since Jesus was talking about a **spiritual Kingdom** there is no need to look  forward to some physical, Eden-like era of kingdom dominance. (John 18:36; Hebrews 12:28;  compare Paul, *The Kingdom of God is righteousness, peace, and joy in the Holy Ghost.* Romans 14:17, 1 Cor. 4:20)  **Already, and Going Strong!**   ***LONG LIVE THE KING!***